# Dataframes sql problem in comparison of two sums

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I want to compare 2 sums from my sql database.
I receive this error.
 ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

```
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle
from pprint import pprint

connection = cx_Oracle.connect("student_ps", "oracle", "xx.xx.xx.xx.x/oracle")

query="""SELECT nume_client, suma_solicitata, suma_depozit, fidelitate
 FROM t_clienti_leasing where varsta>30 and suma_solicitata>10000"""

df = pd.read_sql(query, con=connection, params=None)
pprint(df)
connection.close()

if(df['SUMA_DEPOZIT'] >= df['SUMA_SOLICITATA']):
    df["FIDELITATE"]=="5"

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you cannot use the comparison of two Series in a if statement. The reason is that comparing two Series results in a new Series of booleans indicating the indices where the condition(s) were met.

You should be using .loc like this :

```
df.loc[df['SUMA_DEPOZIT'] >= df['SUMA_SOLICITATA'],"FIDELITATE"] = 5
```

I hope that helped you !